# Off by one error for char-ing string

Tags: java, string, char, off-by-one

This method is supposed to take in a string and output the string as chars however it should be double the size. Example: the string is "PaRty" 
return should be 'P', 'P', 'a', 'a', 'R', 'R', 't', 't', 'Y', 'Y'

For my code, when I run the test it says that the arrays differed at element [];expected: but was:

I can not figure out was is wrong and was hoping someone can help point something out for me to understand and make this work please? And if I am off by one please explain?

```
//Implementing the second method: toExpandedArray, which works with 
//a string and then returns chars of that string. 
public static char[] toExpandedArray(String string)
{
    //Initializing variable needed to char the string
    char[] charArray = new char[string.length() * 2];     

    //The loop that will turn the string into characters.
    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++)
    {            
     charArray[i] = string.charAt(i) ;
     charArray[i+1] = charArray[i];
     i++;
    }

    //Returning the characters as an array.
    return charArray;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your copying logic is incorrect.  You need to copy the letter from index `i` to index `2*i` and `2*i + 1`.  The `i++` at the end is unnecessary; it's already done in the `for` loop.  Change

```
charArray[i] = string.charAt(i);
charArray[i+1] = charArray[i];
i++;
```

to

```
charArray[2*i] = string.charAt(i);
charArray[2*i+1] = string.charAt(i);
```

Comment: Thank you! Is the reason for 2*i because of the previous charArray initialized as string.length * 2?

Comment: So that the character at `0` gets copied to `0` and `1`, the character at `1` gets copied to `2` and `3`, the character at `2` gets copied to `4` and `5`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
string.charAt(i)
```

is incorrect, it should be

```
string.charAt(i/2)
```

you increment i twice each loop.